# how can I read the process tree in hierarchical form of a user in linux

Tags: linux

I know if I type ps -ef I get the processes. But how can I read the process tree of a user say xyz, so that I can draw it in hierarchal form?

Should I read the file path towards process and draw it as a tree structure? Or what?

Here is a selection from a larger ps -ef output:

```
UID  PID   PPID C STIME     TTY    TIME   CMD
....
xyz 15152 15112 0 23:08:00  pts/19 0:00 usr/bin/bash
xyz 15112 15106 0 23:07:54  ?      0:00 /local/openssh/4.5p1/sbin/sshd -R
root 236 6535   0 21:27:06  ?      0:01 /local/openssh/4.5p1/sbin/sshd -R
xyz 15431 15152 0 23:09:30  pts/19 0:00 ps -ef
.....
```

How can I draw the process hierarchy of xyz?

Thanks

Comment: What about `ps ef -u USERNAME` ?

Comment: I did that and I also did ps -ef but i get diff output... why? Also for representing process hierarchy is PID sequence important?

Answer (score 2):

pstree [options] [pid or username]; 
see http://www.linfo.org/pstree.html and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pstree.1.html

Comment: @LogicianUnix-OP is the original poster,i.e.,you here! I guess you wanted to use question there...

Comment: I meant op=original post

Comment: @Tris can you tell me how to read the tree for user xyz? Not how to see in shell..thanks

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "read".  pstree shows the process tree for a pid or user in hierarchical form as you want.  It can be catted into a file for documentation, etc.  In order to understand how to read it look for the procs you are running in `pstree your-user-name'. If necessary start an odd process that keeps running like top and look for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `htop -u USERNAME` and then press <kbd>F5</kbd>

[image]